# Create a graph table in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-graph

I am trying to create a simple node table, using:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100)) AS NODE
```

But whatever I try I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
>    as if it doesn't understand the 'As Node' part.

I am using SQL Server 13.0.1601. 
Database compatibility: SQL Server level 2016(130) 
SSMS: v17.2 
@@version: "Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)   Apr 29 2016 23:23:58   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)"

Comment: Simply, you can't because you have SQL Server 2016 Not 2017.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do `CREATE TABLE (SQL Graph)` in earlier versions of SQL Server, because it applies to SQL Server 2017.

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-sql-graph#examples).

[image]